# How to add a http header when post request to a servicestack web api using servicestack swift plugin?

Tags: swift, servicestack

First below is a very straightforward code that post a req to the api.

```
let req = PurchaseRequest()
req.cellphone = "5101111111"
req.amount = 6
let client = JsonServiceClient(baseUrl: "http://example.com/webapi")
let response = try! client.post(req)
```

Now, how do I add a Http header to the request? For example, there is a http header called "Authorization" and we usually use this header to provide token, to authenticate users. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

```
let client = JsonServiceClient(baseUrl: "http://example.com/webapi")
client.requestFilter = { (req:NSMutableURLRequest) in
    req.addValue("FJEUJFJSKEJF#$"/*a token value*/, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
}
```

So I found the property called requestFilter of the jsonserviceclient, which I can then get the standard nsmutableurlrequest so the rest is easy, just plain old swift code, where I just add my token value to the Authorization http header. My code is doing exactly that.

Comment: OK, I thought my code explains itself but, I guess it could be a little bit vague.